# How to update Illuminate dependecies in Composer package to Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm wondering how to update my composer package to the upcoming Laravel Version 5. I have currently the following dependency:

```
"illuminate/filesystem": "4.*"
```

I want to be able to install my package with Laravel 4 and Laravel 5.

If I leave it at 4.*, and install it with Laravel 5, I think I will end up with two versions of *illuminate/filesystem* (4.* from package and 5.* from Laravel) or the installation will fail.

If I change it to 5.*, I think I break backward compatibility and users won't be able to use the current version of my package with Laravel 4.

Anyone has a tip, how to handle this? I don't want to end up maintaining two branches.

Comment: Laravel5 is not BC, so just create a new package for this release.

Answer (score 0):

If your package is compatible with 4 and 5, then you just need to:

```
"illuminate/filesystem": ">=4.0"
```

And you can be specific:

```
"illuminate/filesystem": "~4.2,~5"
```

Check the docs for more options: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: Sounds right. But Composer outputs warnings about "unbound version constraints".

Comment: Thanks. This looks right. I was not aware, that you can add comma separated versions.